# If a string is compared with an integer, will it evaluate to false?

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, variables, integer

Alright, so I have a `string` and an `integer`. These are both in a `list`. So, later on in the program I check if x value in the `list` is lower than 6. If the value was equal to a string, would it evaluate as false saying that it isn't lower than 6 or would it give me an error? Why is that?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: You couldn't take half a second and run this to figure it out yourself? You could have done that faster than you could click *Ask Question* and type the title of this post. Don't be helpless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will throw an exception on the attempt to compare a string and an integer.

What is the best way to handle the case? There are two main approaches.

One approach tests for type before performing the comparison. The other approach catches the exception and does nothing about it.

There is some debate about which is the better approach. I catch the exception and do nothing about it. It seems simpler to me.

(I would have made this a comment but I'm not allowed to comment.)